# How and when to use filter_xss() and check_plain()?

Tags: security

There are lots of template files like this one `views-view-fields--magazine--magazine.tpl.php` in my website. how and when I should use the filter_xss()  and check_plain() to improve security? for example this is the code:

```
<div>
    <div class="bf-header bf-article-header"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></div>
    <div class="bf-article-body"><?php print $fields['field_magazine_body']->content;?></div>
    <div class="bf-article-image"><?php print $fields['field_magazine_image']->content;?></div>
</div>
<div class="separator article-view-separator"></div>
```

How do I can apply those functions in it?

Comment: Use `filter_xss()` when you want to filter XSS from potentially dangerous content (i.e. content from an untrusted user), and `check_plain()` when you want to escape HTML special characters from a string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, read up about these in the Drupal API:

- [filter_xss](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7)
- [check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7)

So `check_plain()` encodes special characters that has special meaning in HTML (such as `<` and `&`) into plain text entities (i.e. `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively) that will make these be rendered literally (not interpreted as HTML) when that string that is then displayed as part of a page with HTML-markup. The function `filter_xss()` filters an HTML string to prevent cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. It does four things:

- Removing characters and constructs that can trick browsers
- Making sure all HTML entities are well-formed
- Making sure all HTML tags and attributes are well-formed
- Making sure no HTML tags contain URLs with a disallowed protocol (e.g. javascript:)

Both functions are used to sanitize data from users to make sure that any user injection is neutralized before the data is *rendered* on your site.

You never pass the *same string* through *both*.

If you use `check_plain()` then the string passed to the function is supposed to be used as *plain text* (not HTML). Then `filter_xss()` is not needed, since `check_plain()` will always make the string plain text.

If you use `filter_xss()`, then the string passed to the function is supposed to be HTML, and `check_plain()` will mess it up.

When I look at the template you use as example, it looks to me as if all three fields passed to `print()` comes from content that is already sanitized, and need no more sanitation.

However, if you create your *own module* that collects user input without passing it through a "safe" text filter such as "Filtered HTML" or "Plain", you must use these functions for sanitation purposes.

Comment: Where do I can check for inputs come from users? for example there is a content type and anonymous users are allowed to create that kind of nodes.

Comment: @Drupalist, you should never allow the Anonymous user to use an "unsafe" text format.  Navigate to *Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text Formats*.  The "safe" text formats that comes with Drupal are "Filtered HTML" and "Plain text". If these are the *only* formats allowed for the Anonymous user, Drupal performs the required checks for you for any built-in node type and any node type you create with the core **Fields** feature.  If your use case is different from this, ask a new question spelling out the use case.

Comment: Anonymous users are only allowed to use `plain text`

Comment: @Drupalist, that's fine. There is no need to use these functions to sanitize Plain text.

Comment: "ordinary user input into an entity is santized upon input" - this is wrong. Text filters work on output. If input were sanitised then you would see something other than your original input when you edit a field in which you have entered something disallowed.

Comment: ...but that was a succinct explanation of the difference between check_plain and filter_xss so I found your answer very useful. Thank you.

Comment: @crantok, you're right of course (I've corrected the answer).

Comment: Should we use check_plain/filter_xss functions before saving data in to db? or only need to use before render it in the site?

Comment: @ARUN, no. Standard Drupal practice is to *always* save exactly what the user types in the DB, and to sanitize text before rendering.